# Is there a branch of Mathematics which connects Calculus and Discrete Math / Number Theory?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, soft-question, algorithms

I am asking this question out of both curiosity and frustration. There are many problems in computer science which require you to perform operations on a finite set of numbers. It always bothers me that there is no way of mapping this discrete problem onto a continuous one and using the power of calculus to solve it, finally extracting out the answer of the original discrete problem.

Is this not possible? If it is, is there a branch of mathematics which deals with precisely this? Are we confined to solving such problems only by thinking of clever algorithmic techniques?

Thank you for taking the time to answer, and as always, apologies if the questions is silly.

Comment: Complex Analysis

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what you are looking for, but the only thing I am aware of is the use of generating functions in combinatorics

Comment: Analytic number theory meets number theory and calculus, yes.

Comment: Something like this? http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HowTheZerosOfTheZetaFunctionPredictTheDistributionOfPrimes/

Comment: Donald Knuth explores these connections in his book: Concrete Mathematics. Well worth the read if you are a Comp Sci student.

Comment: I would say that statistics and probability do a pretty good job of taking discrete data, assuming some underlying continuous feature, and extracting results via Calculus or its higher analogues (e.g. Measure Theory). There are other areas of math that involve something like connections between the zeta function (number theory) and counting points (discrete mathematics) in finite fields (algebra and algebraic geometry). (I have in mind the Weil Conjectures as a concrete example, but I think the phenomenon of moving between the discrete and continuous is rather common.)

Comment: Just as a side remark, there are also approaches to calculus that keep everything discrete. See, for instance, Peter Saveliev's [Discrete forms and cochains](http://inperc.com/wiki/index.php?title=Discrete_forms_and_cochains).

Comment: I feel like generating functions combine the discrete and the continuous in the same way that the rows of lines on lined paper do; horizontally, they're continuous, and vertically, they're discrete.

Comment: The area of inverse problems's developed in parallel: discrete and continuous: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/On_2D_Inverse_Problems

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The branch of math which connects calculus and combinatorics is called the theory of [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function), or more evocatively [analytic combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_combinatorics). This theory is often used to find asymptotics of combinatorial sequences, such as might occur in the analysis of the running time of some algorithm. [Here](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf) is a free textbook about it.

The branch of math which connects calculus and number theory is called [analytic number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_number_theory).

Comment: Even more so maybe _complex_ analysis (as, I'd argue, the most natural continuation of calculus, in fact) and number theory...

Comment: I recommend the (free, online) book _generatingfunctionology_.

Comment: Is Louis Comtet Book on Combinatorics good one for this subject? along with John Riordan Intro to Combinatorial Analysis?

Answer (score 7):

This is certainly possible. Here is a concrete example that seems to perfectly fit the description "mapping this discrete problem onto a continuous one and using the power of calculus to solve it, finally extracting out the answer of the original discrete problem."

The Ramsey number $r(3, n)$ is defined to be the least natural $N$ with the property that among any $N$ people there are always either three, all of whom know each other, or $n$, none of whom know each other. This is a purely discrete consideration.

Now the asymptotic order of $r(3, n)$ is $\frac{n^2}{\log n}$ and the upper bound proof follows easily from a graph-theoretic fact that is essentially proven by studying the analytic properties of a certain real function.

However, the proof is a bit of an accumulation of little lucky accidents, but is perfectly accessible if you know basic analysis and basic graph theory. You can find a nice exposition here https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~dc340/RamseyLecture3.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Calculus can occasionally be used in extremal combinatorics in order to find a maximizing or minimizing solution to a problem. The only difference is that one must restrain ones solutions in order to get a discrete answer, as opposed to taking any real solution you might find in calculus.

Answer (score 2):

See the book *Concrete Mathematics* by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik ([http://www.amazon.com/Concrete-Mathematics-Foundation-Computer-Science/dp/0201558025](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025)) for a wonderful exposition of connections between CONtinuous and disCRETE mathematics, including number theory.